# Время как признак в ML

Tags: машинное-обучение

В моей задаче обучения используется время. С какой точки зрения можно рассматривать час, день недели, номер недели, номер дня в году и номер месяца? Это категориальные признаки или числовые? Числовой признак, с одной стороны, рассматривает степень чего-либо, что не совсем подходит ко времени, но с другой - если это категориальные признаки, то как их кодировать?

Comment: Можете подробнее описать вашу задачу и привести несколько строк вашего датасета?

Comment: Обычно рассматривают как категориальные. Но нужно подходить очень осторожно к этому делу, там всё не просто. Надо кросс-валидацию правильную делать и т.д. Единственное, что часто рассматривают как числовые признаки - это время дня, но его переводят хитрым образом в синус и косинус, чтобы 23 часа были близко к 0 часов. В общем, Time Series - очень большая тема.

Comment: В [этой статье](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/12/6-powerful-feature-engineering-techniques-time-series/) показано как создавать базовые признаки из временного ряда